# Handling Self-Intersecting Regions

Tags: regions, mesh, polygons

I am trying to test various parametric regions of a function for membership of the origin (point {0,0}). I generate the boundary by creating four parametric boundary curves, and then use RegionMember to tell whether the origin is inside the region (indicating a root of the function). However, the function often overlaps itself, as is shown in the result from my code below. The MeshBoundaryRegion function below gives an error of the form

```
BoundaryMeshRegion::binsect: The boundary curves self-intersect or cross each other in...
```

Consequently, RegionMember also throws an error. I also tried creating the region as a polygon, but I found that RegionMember also did not work with the resultant region. (It simply did not evaluate.) The code is below.

```
l = 1;
j = 4;
i = 2;
wint = Re[zGrid[[j, i + 0]]] Abs[Ws[snorm]];
wfin = Re[zGrid[[j, i + 1]]] Abs[Ws[snorm]];
yint = Im[zGrid[[j + 0, i]]] Abs[Ws[snorm]];
yfin = Im[zGrid[[j + 1, i]]] Abs[Ws[snorm]];
wres = 36;
yres = 36;
winc = (wfin - wint)/(wres - 1);
yinc = (yfin - yint)/(yres - 1);
w = Table[wint + (i - 1) winc, {i, wres}];
y = Table[yint + (i - 1) yinc, {i, yres}];

paraTab1 = Table[{Re[f[k[[l]], w[[i]], yint]], Im[f[k[[l]], w[[i]], yint]]}, {i, wres}];
paraTab2 = Table[{Re[f[k[[l]], wfin, y[[i]]]], Im[f[k[[l]], wfin, y[[i]]]]}, {i, yres}];
paraTab3 = Table[{Re[f[k[[l]], w[[wres - i + 1]], yfin]], Im[f[k[[l]], w[[wres - i + 1]], yfin]]}, {i, wres}];
paraTab4 = Table[{Re[f[k[[l]], wint, y[[wres - i + 1]]]], Im[f[k[[l]], wint, y[[yres - i + 1]]]]}, {i, yres}]; 

paraTabFullEx = Join[paraTab1, paraTab2, paraTab3, paraTab4]/norm;

SetOptions[Graphics,
  ImageSize -> Large,
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
  GridLines -> {{0}, {0}},
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, FontFamily -> "Cambria", FontSize -> 20]
];

paraTabEx = Delete[paraTabFullEx, {{wres}, {wres + yres}, {2 wres + yres}, {2 wres + 2 yres}}];

Rg = BoundaryMeshRegion[paraTabEx, Line[Join[Table[n, {n, Length[paraTabEx]}], {1}]]];

paraTabLinEx = Line[Join[paraTabEx, {paraTab1[[1]]/norm}]];
Graphics[paraTabLinEx]

poly = Polygon[paraTabEx];
Graphics[poly]
```

[image]

Another, perhaps more visually comprehensible, example is below. (Please disregard the badly formatted tick labels.)

[image]

Notice that in this second example, the function does not pass through the origin; the small inner loop is not part of the region.

Is there a way to break the space traced out of the function into overlapping and non-overlapping components? Alternatively, is there a better approach that I should consider? Increasing the resolution of the function space sample has proven prohibitively computationally expensive.

Thank you

To actually replicate these results, the full code below is needed

```
(* Fundamental Constants *)
\[Mu]0 = 4 \[Pi] 10^-7; (* H m^-1 *)
c = 299792458; (* m s^-1 *)
ep0 = 1/(\[Mu]0 c^2); (* F m^-1 *)
eEl = (1.6021766`64*10^-19); (* C *)
evtj = 1.602177`164 10^-19; (* J *)
me = 9.10938`64 10^-31; (* kg *)
mH = 1.672622`64 10^-27; (* kg *)
ZH = 1; (* C *)

(* Control Parameters *)
s = {"e", "i"};

ionSpec = "H";

mr = 1836;

ni = 1*10^18;(* m^-3 *)

TeeV = 185;(* eV *)
Tre = 1;
TieV = 50;(* eV *)
Tri = 10;

B = 0.014`64; (* T *)

(* Derived Constants *)
Ns = Length[s];

mi = ToExpression["m" <> ionSpec] (mr/(mH/me));
Zi = ToExpression["Z" <> ionSpec];

qe = -eEl;
qi = Zi eEl;

ne = Zi ni;(* m^-3 *)

Te = TeeV evtj;(* J *)
Ti = TieV evtj;(* J *)

Ts[s_] := ToExpression["T" <> s];
Trs[s_] := ToExpression["Tr" <> s];
ms[s_] := ToExpression["m" <> s];
qs[s_] := ToExpression["q" <> s];
ns[s_] := ToExpression["n" <> s];
trm[s_] := ToExpression[s <> "trm"];

Ws[s_] := (qs[s] B)/ms[s]; (* s^-1 *)

ws[s_] := Sqrt[(ns[s] qs[s]^2)/(ep0 ms[s])]; (* s^-1 *)

vtsl[s_] := Sqrt[Ts[s]/ms[s]];(* m s^-1 *)

ys[s_] := Trs[s] - 1;

(* Functions *)
z[k_, w_, m_, s_] := (w - m Ws[s])/(k vtsl[s]);

W[z_] := 1 - Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] (Erfi[z/Sqrt[2]] - I) z E^(-z^2/2);

Z[z_] := -Sqrt[(\[Pi]/2)] (Erfi[z/Sqrt[2]] - I) E^(-z^2/2);

(* Dielectric Response Function Components *)

IT := ( {
{1, 0, 0},
{0, 1, 0},
{0, 0, 0}
} );

Ab[k_, w_, s_] := ( {
{ys[s], 0, 0},
{0, ys[s], 0},
{0, 0, (z[k, w, 0, s])^2 W[z[k, w, 0, s]]}
} );

Bb = 1/2 ( {
 {1, I, 0},
 {-I, 1, 0},
 {0, 0, 0}
} );

eps[k_, w_, mMax_, s_] := -(ws[s]/w)^2 (Ab[k, w, s] + Bb (ys[s] z[k, w, +1, s] + z[k, w, 0, s]) Z[z[k, w, +1, s]] + Bb\[Conjugate] (ys[s] z[k, w, -1, s] + z[k, w, 0, s]) Z[z[k, w, -1, s]]);

ep[k_, w_] := IdentityMatrix[3] - \!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(Ns\)]\(eps[k, w, trm[s[\([i]\)]], s[\([i]\)]]\)\);
delta[k_, w_] := ep[k, w] - ((k c)/w)^2 IT;
f[k_, w_, y_] := Det[delta[+k, w + I y]] Det[delta[-k, w + I y]];

snorm = "i";
knorm = c/\[Omega]s["i"];

kint = (015/100)/knorm;
kfin = (300/100)/knorm;
kpow = 4;
kres = 2^kpow;
kinc = (kfin - kint)/(kres - 1);
k = Table[kint + (i - 1) kinc, {i, kres}];

lowfr = 1/10;

xxmin = lowfr;
xxmax = (2/2);
xxres = 16;
xxinc = (xxmax - xxmin)/(xxres - 1);
xx = Table[xxmin + (i - 1) xxinc, {i, xxres}];

yymin = -(1/10);
yymax = (30/100);
yyres = 16;
yyinc = (yymax - yymin)/(yyres - 1);
yy = Table[ymin + (i - 1) yyinc, {i, yyres}];

zGrid = Table[xx[[i]] + I yy[[j]], {j, yyres}, {i, xxres}];
```

Use l = 1 in the first block of code. The ordered pair j = 4 and i = 2 produce the other plot above. Please let me know if the code above does not run properly.

Comment: You've included the code, and made your question clear, that is fantastic.  But I'm missing a few definitions, without which I can't run it.  `zGrid`, `Ws`, `snorm`, `f`, `k`, and `norm` are all still blue after I run the code.

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: JasonB, thank you so much for trying to get it running. Unfortunately, many of those quantities I can't give simple definitions here for you. It would be far more helpful if I could simply provide my whole .nb file.

Comment: The second block of code should provide the needed definitions.

Comment: maybe forget region functions and just directly implement the winding rule?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the winding rule. Could you please explain it?

Comment: good explanation here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number (and of course there are other ways to define being inside a self overlapping curve ,up to you to know what you want ).   Note you could also discretize the curve to a polygon and use a polygon inside test. That will have some loss of precision though.